# How to compile DPDK application such as examples to support C++?

Tags: c++, c, dpdk

How should I modify Makefiles of DPDK to support c++ compilation? I tried by adding `CFLAGS += -lstdc++` to the Makefile of the helloworld example but it seems not working. Is there a more standard way to do that?

Edited:
I'm using the makefile of helloworld example in DPDK 20.08 with some small modifications. I'm building it on ubuntu 20.04 ,and which is not cross-compilation. The DPDK is built with dpdk-setup script and not meson. The makefile is

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause
# Copyright(c) 2010-2014 Intel Corporation

# binary name
APP = rss_helper

# all source are stored in SRCS-y
# SRCS-y := main.c
SRCS-y := test.cpp

# Build using pkg-config variables if possible
ifeq ($(shell pkg-config --exists libdpdk && echo 0),0)

all: shared
# all: static
.PHONY: shared static
shared: build/$(APP)-shared
    ln -sf $(APP)-shared build/$(APP)
static: build/$(APP)-static
    ln -sf $(APP)-static build/$(APP)

PKGCONF ?= pkg-config

PC_FILE := $(shell $(PKGCONF) --path libdpdk 2>/dev/null)
CFLAGS += -O3 $(shell $(PKGCONF) --cflags libdpdk)
LDFLAGS_SHARED = $(shell $(PKGCONF) --libs libdpdk)
LDFLAGS_STATIC = $(shell $(PKGCONF) --static --libs libdpdk)

build/$(APP)-shared: $(SRCS-y) Makefile $(PC_FILE) | build
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRCS-y) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS_SHARED)

build/$(APP)-static: $(SRCS-y) Makefile $(PC_FILE) | build
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRCS-y) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS_STATIC)

build:
    @mkdir -p $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f build/$(APP) build/$(APP)-static build/$(APP)-shared
    test -d build && rmdir -p build || true

else

ifeq ($(RTE_SDK),)
$(error "Please define RTE_SDK environment variable")
endif

# Default target, detect a build directory, by looking for a path with a .config
RTE_TARGET ?= $(notdir $(abspath $(dir $(firstword $(wildcard $(RTE_SDK)/*/.config)))))

include $(RTE_SDK)/mk/rte.vars.mk

CPPFLAGS += -O3
CPPFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)
CPPFLAGS += -DALLOW_EXPERIMENTAL_API
CPPFLAGS += -lstdc++

include $(RTE_SDK)/mk/rte.extapp.mk

endif
```

I changed the name of the source file and flags. The source file test.cpp contains only iostream header and an empty main function (just for test). There are two errors:

1. can't find the `test.cpp` with  `cpp` on. It works find when replace `test.cpp` in makefile with `test.c` while keeping the actual source file name as `test.cpp`.

```
    LD rss_helper
    gcc: error: test.cpp: No such file or directory
    make[1]: *** [/home/syk/dpdk-20.08/mk/rte.app.mk:456: rss_helper] Error 1
    make: *** [/home/syk/dpdk-20.08/mk/rte.extapp.mk:15: all] Error 2
```

2. Error for LD like below

```
g++  -O3 -W -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wold-style-definition -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wnested-externs -Wcast-qual -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wdeprecated -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-address-of-packed-member -DALLOW_EXPERIMENTAL_API -lstdc++  -c -o test.o /home/syk/loadbalancing/rss_helper_demo/test.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wmissing-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wold-style-definition’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wnested-externs’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
  LD rss_helper
/usr/bin/ld: test.o: in function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_main':
test.cpp:(.text.startup+0x20): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text.startup+0x27): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [/home/syk/dpdk-20.08/mk/rte.app.mk:456: rss_helper] Error 1
make: *** [/home/syk/dpdk-20.08/mk/rte.extapp.mk:15: all] Error 2
```

I tried to resolve it by added `-lstdc++` but still had it.

Edited-2：
The source file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <rte_eal.h>
using namespace std;

class A{
    int a;
};

int
main(void){
    return 0;
}
```

It can't include iostream and rte_eal either.

Comment: please share the proper details like DPDK version, is hand `built Makefile, or Cmakefile, is DPDK installed with meson, is it cross-build, is on Linux/BSD/windows?`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've added information and logs in the question.

Comment: thanks for the update, can also share the sample code snippet so I can try reproducing the same.

Comment: Updated. I'm starting by trying to include the headers first.

Comment: will have a look  into this shortly

Comment: I am able to build it properly posting the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 2 possible ways to solve this issue

1. set environment `set CC=g++`. Then execute `make`
2. edit `Makefile` to add `CC = g++`

with these changes I am able build and run the sample code.

```
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff0a3e6000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f1389440000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f138904f000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1388cb1000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f13899cb000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f1388a99000)
```

and

```
ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=6e3fb6ed5f48b8f66fe4c05118f7b6bf6a9a1235, not stripped
```

Comment: @Lowsteam tested the same with enablng `#include <rte_eal.h>`

Comment: @LowSteam, please accept and upvote to close the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the makefile inorder to adapt C++:
You need to change `CFLAGS` to `CPPFLAGS`
See below reference example:

```
ifeq ($(RTE_SDK),)
$(error "Please define RTE_SDK environment variable")
endif
 
# Default target, can be overriden by command line or environment
RTE_TARGET ?= x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc
 
include $(RTE_SDK)/mk/rte.vars.mk
 
# binary name
APP = dpdkrecv
 
# all source are stored in SRCS-y
SRCS-y := main.c syncshm.c cqf.cpp countingquotientfilter.cpp murmurhash3.cpp
 
CPPFLAGS += -O3 -mbmi2
CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)
 
include $(RTE_SDK)/mk/rte.extapp.mk
```

Comment: I'm using the CPPFLAGS like 
```CPPFLAGS += -O3
CPPFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)
CPPFLAGS += -DALLOW_EXPERIMENTAL_API
CPPFLAGS += -lstdc++```, and it's compiling using g++, but still some faults like errors to load when including iostream and not able to find source file ending with cpp. How can I fix it?

Comment: You can Try with this way : ``CPPFLAGS += -O3 $(WERROR_FLAGS) -lstdc++ ``

Comment: @Altaf this true if you were using DPDK < 20.11. This is drastically changed from 20.11 and above. Hence I humbly request to re-edit the answer covering both,. (please note I will tag this as not an answer, please edit and will approve)

Answer (score 0):

Please share the Makefile,

I am adding

> #include algorithm

dpdk ver: dpdk-stable-18.11.2 ,
build with

> sudo make install T=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc DESTDIR=install